# Multi-Character Command Parsing in Python getopt

Tags: python, getopt, command-line-arguments

I have been using python getopt for parsing, both short and long and it worked great. Now I need to add some more short variables in getopt function and it would look better, if I need to have multi characters as getopt:short. Is there a way to do something like this.

```
getopt.getopt(argv,"hf:c:d:pv:pz:","")
```

Here, I need to access pv and pz as a individual command line arguments instead of the getopt reading it as 'p with no args', 'v with one args'. I tried 'pv:' [pv:] inside the quotes, but it recognized pv, but does not read the args.

Also,(on a different note) is it possible to have more than one inputs for the same args. Please pardon me, if you this is a very simple answer.

Comment: You may want to convert your option parsing to [argparse](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html) instead, or [optparse](http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html) if not yet on Python 2.7.

Comment: I am in 2.4.3.... Lab Machine, cant do much.... :(

Comment: Use [optparse](http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html) then, still vastly better than getopt.

Comment: ^Yeah sure, I will add that for main project, I am just prototyping now... any simple hack will work....Thanks

Comment: Also note that short options can be combined into one switch (think `-tzvf` instead of `-t -z -v -f`) and thus having short options with more than one character is generally not supported by argument parsers.

Comment: I see, thanks...., How about having more than one argument for short options?

Comment: optparse supports multi-value arguments out-of-the-box (store type append, or use `nargs` with a value greater than 1).

Comment: ^ I guess I can use comma and use split(',').... Thanks everyone...

Answer (score 2):

Based on my understanding of the documentation and research I did when I needed the same thing as you, there is no way to do it. `shortopts` with prefix "-" only work with one character, for more than one character, you must use `longopts`, which use the prefix "--".

Example in python3:

```
import sys, getopt

try:
    opts, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], 'c:d:', ['hf','pv','pz'])
except getopt.GetoptError as e:
    print(str(e))

for o, a in opts:
    print(o, ':', a)
```

Unfortunately, I think there is no way to put `longopts` with a required argument, but this can be solved with a manual check.

For more information, i recommend consulting the documentation:
https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/getopt.html